# how to prevent MpaAndroidChart LineChart's highlight be unselect by tap

Tags: mpandroidchart

In my lineChart, I never want user to deselect a value. how can I prevent the deselect? I haven't find any API which can make this in the document

Answer (score 0):

fix the issue by myself via PR [prevent deselect hightlighting per tap](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/pull/3260)